# Accessing photo album to check if a photo already exists

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, photo

say I'm having an array of dictionaries. Every dictionary has two objects: Name and Location. You might guess where I'm going with this: I'm using this to get the name of a selected item somewhere in my app, and check if there exists a photo with the same name (+ extension?).

I can save photo's with that name, but is there any way to check the Photo Album if that photo(name) already exists? If it is, is there a away to load that photo with that name into my app?

The internet is a bit vague about this (never a clear answer), so I'm asking you guys, the smart ones on SO! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a way to get a list of files in the photo album.

As far as I'm aware the only way to access the photo album is by using UIImagePickerController class, which enables the user to select an image which is then passed to you app.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought as well, but I'm quite new to it so I hoped to receive a different answer. I'm gonna google around a bit more but I'm afraid I'll have to accept this answer :(